# How to return back element in Zp using pow?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

For example I have value 2

```
2**17 % 31 = 4
4**23 % 31 = 2
```

And return value 2

What is the name of that equation, and how to find pairs like (17,23) over mod 31 ?
It is not modinverse,

```
modinverse(17,31) = 11
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), which your programming language may or may not contain.

If $\log$ is the discrete logarithm in the finite group $\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z}$, then your examples are $\log_2(4) = 17$ and $\log_4(2) = 23$.